# http vs sql queries

Tags: mysql

i have big problem deciding what approach to take, i have many pages on my site that uses tabs. for example a page with 5 tabs (horizontal tabs).

now every tab takes data from different table in the db, i have 2 option from what i see:
1. when the page load, make 5 mysql queries, and load all the data to all 5 tabs at once.

2. make 1 mysql query when first the page load, and then load with ajax php script everytime a user click on another tab. 
   the php script will generate 1 sql query, and will generate also 1 http request.

i'm using apache. what do you think?

Comment: 5 queries is not that much : how many rows are you retrieving?  If you are really concerned about performance you should consider caching the query results on server side.

Comment: the max row i retrieve is 150 probably per table, do you have good guide or reference about caching in mysql?

Comment: The caching should be done with the server side scripting.  What are you using?  PHP, Java, other?

Comment: 150*5 = 750 rows per page load is considered alot? this is the max row ill get from the 5 queries

Comment: Do you have many users?  Do you need to refresh the page very often?  Try it first and see if you have a performance problem.  If you want to implement a cache system have a look at [Memcached](http://php.net/memcached).

Comment: Try it both ways.  Seriously; it would be (1) good practice, and (2) answer your question.  You may find that you start with one way and later decide to switch to the other.